# Driving a butterfly package DFB laser

Tags: driver, bias, laser, laser-diode, laser-driver

I want to drive a DFB laser in a type-2, 14-pin butterfly package. The manufacturer has provided limited information on how to bias the laser diode and could not get any information on the reference or test circuit.

The laser diode's anode is connected to the case ground. I need to DC bias the cathode with a voltage of 2V at a maximum of 200mA current using a constant current source to drive the laser without damaging it. And, I do not want to monitor its output with the internal photo diode. I just want to bias the laser diode.

I have been researching for some circuits, they are either using LM317 or very complex circuits using integrated ICs with additional controls and functionalities.

I am looking for a very simple circuit to bias my laser. Please help!

Datasheet: http://ao-inc.com/images/uploads/products/01-05-1347_DFB-XXX-BF-XX-CW-FX-HX-N347_REV_001.pdf

Comment: The information you have are not sufficient for the task: you can bias the laser diode by *any* current source, but if you do not know what is a safe value for the anode current, you'll probably destroy it in few seconds.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri what information should I additionally post in the question?

Comment: Model number of the laser, reference to the datasheet.

Comment: DFB lasers appear to be fairly expensive, in which case I would think "correct" would trump "cheap and simple" when designing a driver.  Or maybe all I found were the expensive ones, and there's someplace that sells them in baggies for the price of a bag of potato chips.

Comment: @JRE Not "cheap", just simple to implement and control. I want to avoid unnecessary features and monitoring.

Comment: Do you have access to the average electronics lab? Because these usually have bench supplies that you can set to a maximum current. Use that to set the current you want. Done?

Comment: I think you **need** features and monitoring.  The manufacturer put a photodiode in there to monitor optical power.   They put a thermistor in there to monitor temperature.  They put a thermoelectric cooling device in it to cool it.  I don't think they put all of that in there because it isn't needed.

Comment: Yes, I am monitoring the thermistor changes and controlling the TEC. I just don't want to use the PD. I am monitoring the LD output externally because the internal PD is a low efficiency device.

Comment: Not using the internal photodiode is asking for trouble. Did they ship you a photodiode calibration value with the device?

Comment: I can't imagine any circuit that is simpler than using an LM317 and a resistor. Why do you have a problem with thant?

Comment: @Andyaka I have used these lasers and disagree about the internal photodiode. It's there as a convenience feature. If you're monitoring the optical power externally it's not essential to use it. The TEC and thermistor on the other hand are essential if you want the output to be stable and at the correct wavelength.

Comment: @pericynthion, If you use an external photodiode for laser current control, you'd better be careful nobody ever disconnects the output fiber. Ideally you'd have the components needed for feedback fusion spliced on to the output fiber rather than connectorized.

Comment: I agree with @pericynthion. I'm better off not using the internal PD because I have a very efficiency laser output monitoring externally.

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, the output fiber is never disconnected.

Comment: A current limit would serve to protect the laser as well as or better than photodiode monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an application note on *Current Sources for Fiber Optic Lasers*, Application Note 90 by Jim Williams of LTC.

The *Grounded Anode Current Source* circuit is suitable to drive my laser. The circuit also has current limiting, over-voltage protection, and self enable (for slow start). And I have designed a circuit using MAX1979 to control the internal TEC temperature. These two should ensure proper current and temperature control required for the safe operation of my laser.